# Quickblox messaging fetch last n messages

Tags: ios, quickblox, instant-messaging

I'm using the Quickblox iOS SDK for instant messaging in my app. When a user logs in I retrieve the list of messages. I am trying to retrieve the last N messages. I use extended request parameters as specified in this document:
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#List_chat_messages

This call retrieves the first 100 messages, not the most recent ones.
I also checked out the list of parameters to send from here:
http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Retrieve_messages

Using a combination of the limit and sort parameters still does not give the desired result.

1. How can I make a request to retrieve the last N messages in a dialog?
2. How can I load last but N messages? for example, last 100 messages before the most recent 100. Similar to limit 100, but skip 100, in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

//Try this out:

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
extendedRequest[@"date_sent[lte]"]= @([now timeIntervalSince1970]);
extendedRequest[@"sort_desc"]= @"date_sent";

//get the most recent 50 messages
extendedRequest[@"limit"] = @(50);
[QBChat messagesWithDialogID:self.dialog.ID extendedRequest:extendedRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: @IgorKhomenko i have tried like this. Still last few messages got skipped in the history list.     QBChatDialog chatDialog = new QBChatDialog(privateDialog.getDialogId());
        QBMessageGetBuilder messageGetBuilder = new QBMessageGetBuilder();
        messageGetBuilder.setLimit(50);
        messageGetBuilder.sortDesc("date_sent");

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue in Android .

Solved it as following .
All you have to do is add a parameter in requestbuilder sortDesc("date_sent");

```
QBDialog dlg=new QBDialog(str_dialogid);
    QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    requestBuilder.setLimit(10);
    requestBuilder.sortDesc("date_sent");
```

Comment: i had used the same.. it skipped last ten messages.