# QuickBlox history returns only first messages

Tags: chat, history, quickblox

QuickBlox returns only 50 chat messages and I know this is a known limit if I don't specify the extendedRequest LIMIT and SKIP, but my problem is I want the LAST 50 messages and not the first 50 messages. I tried the `extendedRequest[@"sort_desc"] = @"last_message_date_sent"` but QB is returning random messages, not the last and not the first.

This issue occurs in Q-Municate also. I created a chat with a friend and sent him N messages, and only first few messages are returned.

So, is there a way to return only the last 50 messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer from Igor Khomenko in this topic: [Quickblox messaging fetch last n messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981259/quickblox-messaging-fetch-last-n-messages)

and applied. It was correct and I improved inverting the Array with the messages, to show correctly to the user:

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
extendedRequest[@"date_sent[lte]"]= @([now timeIntervalSince1970]);
extendedRequest[@"sort_desc"]= @"date_sent";

//get the most recent 50 messages
extendedRequest[@"limit"] = @(100);
```

and when I have the Array populated, I just invert it with:

```
[[self.messages reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

and everything was fine!

Igor, the same issue occurs in Q-Municate, and thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not getting reverse message array  via using [[self.messages reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
Could you tell me what I am doing wrong